# Generic exception with String parameter

Tags: haskell, exception

I'm just wondering if there is any generic exception that I can throw in case I don't want to create custom one for example in some simple scripts.

I'm looking for an exception that takes a single `String` as a reason.

As an example the `NoMethodError`, however it has a specific semantics and I want a generic one.
https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.16.0.0/docs/Control-Exception.html#t:NoMethodError

Comment: Are you looking for [`error`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.16.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:error)? It returns an [`ErrorCall`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.16.0.0/docs/Control-Exception.html#t:ErrorCall)

Comment: @Vikstapolis you are right, that looks like something I'm looking for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends on exactly what you want to do.

If you want to throw an IO error then you can just call [`error`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.16.0.0/docs/Control-Exception.html#t:ErrorCall), which generates an [`ErrorCall`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.16.0.0/docs/Control-Exception.html#t:ErrorCall) exception. You can optionally catch that in your `main` function and produce a more user-friendly error message. This is roughly equivalent to what most other programming languages provide in the way of exception handling.

If you have some non-IO computations which might fail at various stages (e.g. looking something up in a `Map` and not finding it) then you can use [`Either String`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.16.0.0/docs/Data-Either.html) as a quick-and-dirty exception monad. The equivalent of throwing an exception is `Left`.

To make `Either String` a bit more powerful you can import [`Control.Monad.Except`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/mtl-2.2.2/docs/Control-Monad-Except.html). This introduces the `MonadError` typeclass, which includes `Either` as an instance. Hence by importing it you can use `throwError` and `catchError`.

Alternatively you can use the [`ExceptT`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/mtl-2.2.2/docs/Control-Monad-Except.html#t:ExceptT) monad transformer (also part of `Control.Monad.Except`) to add exceptions to any other monad you happen to be working with.

Comment: Thanks! The error function looks like the thing I was looking for.

Comment: If you want to throw an `IO` error, I recommend `fail` over `error`. Its type helps the compiler let you know if you accidentally try to lazily defer an error to later. For example, `catch (error <$> getLine) (\e -> putStrLn "this doesn't get printed")` doesn't invoke its error handler, but `catch (fail <$> getLine) (\e -> putStrLn "type error")` doesn't compile and gives you a chance to correct it to `catch (getLine >>= fail) (\e -> putStrLn "this gets printed")`.